# Page DOM doesn't update after javascript edit

Tags: javascript, youtube, wmode

I've got this example page where I'm trying to put the wmode of every youtube element inside the page to "transparent".

With Chrome and its inspector I notice that my javascript works but the browser view doesn't update and the overlay still is under the youtube video. If I put the wmode property directly in the HTML though and I open it in Chrome everything is ok and the video is UNDER the div.

Here is the page
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/4064417/provaJs.html

Any suggestion why it's behaving like this?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/534474/changing-arbitrary-flash-objects-wmode-to-transparent You basically need to wrap the object in another element (*after changing `wmode`*) so that the element is redrawn..

Comment: I can't use jquery in my code =\

Comment: there is a vanilla JS solution in another answer..

Answer (score 0):

Try forcing the browser to redraw the flash element

```
FlashElement.style.display = "none";
FlashElement.style.display = "block";
```

Comment: Actually this works, thank you very much. If someone knows better ways is welcome =)